# Rails 3 delete all elements of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to delete an array of users but the way I have it it is deleting one by one. Is there a better way to do it?

My code is:

```
@users ||= User.where("clicks_given - clicks_received < ?", -5).to_a
@users.each do |user|
  user.destroy
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use Rails' built-in methods. Note that you need to wrap your query in an array (if you're interpolating variables) when using these methods.

To iterate over each one calling destroy (which will run callbacks, etc.):

```
User.destroy_all(["clicks_given - clicks_received < ?", -5])
```

Or to just delete these in the database in a single query (no iteration over each item), you can do this, but keep in mind it won't run your callbacks:

```
User.delete_all(["clicks_given - clicks_received < ?", -5])
```

Comment: @dmarkow, I was just updating my answer with destroy_all as well - not trying to copy your answer.

Comment: And I have upvoted you both. However it said that `delete_all` and `destroy_all` can not take two arguments.

Comment: It's working. If I have no callbacks, isn't it better to wipe them out with a single query?

Comment: Yes, with no callbacks, dependencies, etc., it will be much quicker, especially with many records. Otherwise, an ActiveRecord object is instantiated for every single record.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `destroy_all` method:

```
User.destroy_all("clicks_given - clicks_received < ?", -5)
```

**Reference:** http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.5/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all

I've also used the following before:

```
@users.map(&:destroy)
```

It's essentially doing the same thing as your each call, but you can avoid the boiler-plate code.